# MobiLink Profiler fails to start on ONE instance of SQL Anywhere. Error seems to indicate that it's not finding the Java folder

Tags: sqlanywhere, mobilink

We run a server with multiple SQL databases communicating SQLAnywhere on remote devices via MobiLink 17. On all of the databases I am able to start the MobiLink Profiler except for one. When I try, I get a message on the Profiler: "I/O error when receiving authentication result." The MobiLink log says:

E. 2024-01-03 10:44:04. <1> [-10018] Error fetching connection script begin_connection_autocommit

E. 2024-01-03 10:45:06. <2> [-10127] Failed to load necessary Java class: ianywhere.message.sync.SynchronizationTask from classpath: 'D:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64..\java\mlscript.jar;D:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64..\java\jodbc4.jar;D:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64..\java\mlnotif.jar;D:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64..\java\mlsupport.jar;C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 16\bin64..\java\mailapi.jar;C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 16\bin64..\java\pop3.jar;C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 16\bin64..\java\imap.jar;C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 16\bin64..\java\smtp.jar;D:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64..\java\mlstream.jar;;D:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64..\java\jsyblib1700.jar;.'

This part

D:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64..\java\

looks like it's looking for a "java" folder somewhere in the subdirectories of bin64. But the files that Profiler is looking for are in D:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\Java. If this is the case, something is telling MobiLink to look in bin64 for this database and none of the others. I've been through everything I can think of, from the cmd files that load the MobiLink service to the registry, and I can't find this.

It might be related that there doesn't seem to be a classpath variable set, at least not globally. Typing "echo %classpath%" in a command prompt just returns "%classpath%" instead of a path to a file.

In the list of MobiLink error codes (https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/8534f27c56354283bd00fc8f77adaf94/810a69d46ce21014b48be5a5100e947b.html?version=17.0) 10017 and 10127 don't seem to be related to this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.